# Can you use ID on elements in Gatsby.js (JSX)?

Tags: jsx, gatsby

I'm building out a navbar component using Gatsby.js. I've added an input and corresponding label which is throwing the error shown in the image below:

[image: "Unterminated JSX contents" with error pointing towards closing tag of]

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import * as styles from "../styles/navbar.module.scss" 

   const Navbar = () => {
      return (
    
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
        <label for="menu" onclick></label>
    
        <nav role="off-canvas">
          <ul className={styles.navbar}>
            <li><Link to="/page-1">Page 1</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/page-2">Page 2</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/page-3">Page 3</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      )
    }

export default Navbar
```

I'm thinking the error has to do with the ID usage within the label and input tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem in the snippet above is that your `Navbar` returning JSX structure is not being wrapped by anything (even you have an unclosed `input` tag).
It's perfectly valid to use `id`s on your elements, it has nothing to do with using it.

Just use:

```
   const Navbar = () => {
      return (
        <>
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu" />
        <label for="menu" onclick></label>
    
        <nav role="off-canvas">
          <ul className={styles.navbar}>
            <li><Link to="/page-1">Page 1</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/page-2">Page 2</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/page-3">Page 3</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
       </>
      )
    }
```

`<>` is a React fragment shorthand for `<React.Fragment>` and they allow you to wrap children without modifying DOM structure. More details: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Ahhh, I am very new to React and did not know about React fragments. Thanks for the thorough response!